# How to redirect to Laravel route when call came from JS Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to create a redirect to a route in laravel controller where the call to this controller came from an Ajax call in a js file.

Example: I loaded a view `localhost:8000/viewone`, in this view I run a js code that does an Ajax call to a Laravel route : `routeone`. In the controller function linked to `routeone`, the code does some data processing and then needs to load an other view : `viewTwo`.

The problem is that the `viewTwo`loading doesn't occur and all I get is the view HTML code in my return statement in `onsuccess` function of the Ajax call.

**What I tried :**

Create a controller inked to `viewTwo` by creating a new route `routeTwo`,
in my `routeone`controller I redirect to this route with session data.

`return redirect()->route('routeTwo')->with(['data'=>$data])`

In the `routeTwo`controller I get the session data and return the `viewTwo`.

```
$data = \Session::get('data');
return view('viewTwo',['data'=>$data]);
```

It still doesn't work. What happens is that `viewTwo`loading happens as an XHR request and I get the HTML page which would have been loaded in the main browser view ( like the first view ) as XHR response data.

**Question :** How to force redirect to/load view when call came from Js AJAX function.

Comment: my opinion u can redirect or change view  by `angular ui router` otherwise use `vue-router` for using like this

Comment: @JigneshJoisar I use Jquery as my Javascript Ajax library, those really don't exist for me

Comment: You can try `if ($request->wantsJson()) { ... }`

Comment: @kerbholz then ? would this make my return statement not to the Ajax request ?

Comment: From the javascript, After getting the response from AJAX call you can redirect using `document.location.href`

Comment: I had a problem with js redirecting as query data was a link. I did fix this by converting to base64 then decoding base64 in my `viewtwo` controller.

Answer (score 0):

by load or render html from ajax do like this in first view page

```
<div class="newView"></div>
```

by ajax success function add this line

```
$('.newView').html(data.html);
```

in controller

```
$view = view("viewnamewhatuhave",compact('data'))->render();
```

by view facade

```
$view =  View::make('viewnamewhatuhaveset',[$data])->render();

return response()->json(['html' => $view]);
```